# Button handling and layer visibility in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, dom-events, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script that I've been building for a game. The idea is to have info about the game in a div that will pop up when a button (which is added by my script) on the page is clicked.

I'm using z-index because when I just display the div over the top of the game screen, some of the images show through. So, basically what I need to do is change the z-index of my div based on the value of a variable and/or button click. However, I cannot get my div to come to the front when I click my button.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Test Script
// @namespace       http://therealmsbeyond.com/
// @description     Test
// @include         an_include.js
// @include         another_include.js
// @require         json.js
// ==/UserScript==

var VERSION = 1;
var WEBSITEURL = 'http://therealmsbeyond.com/';
var SCRIPTNAME = 'Test';
var SENDINFODELAY = 600000;
var UPDATEDELAY = 604800000;

var ZINDEX_UNDER = -100;
var ZINDEX_OVER = 111111;

var Options = {
    'mapVisible' : false,
    'showHostile' : false,
    'showAlliance' : false,
    'showBookmarks' : false
}

function custom_setValue(k,v){
    GM_setValue(k,v);
}
function custom_getValue(k,dv){
    return(GM_getValue(k,dv));
}
function custom_deleteValue(k){
    GM_deleteValue(k);
}
function getSavedInfo(){
    return(custom_getValue('ajaxparams',null));
}
function getSavedServerId(){
    return(custom_getValue('sid'));
}

var e = document.createElement('div');
    var idAttr = document.createAttribute('id');
    var styleAttr = document.createAttribute('style');
    idAttr.nodeValue = 'shadow_map_container';
    styleAttr.nodeValue = 'background-color:white;top:150px;left:75px;position:absolute;height:600px;width:600px;';
    e.setAttributeNode(idAttr);
    e.setAttributeNode(styleAttr);

    var c = '<strong>This is the map window.</strong>';
    e.innerHTML = c;
    document.body.appendChild(e);

if(Options.mapVisible == true)
{
    document.getElementById('shadow_map_container').style.zIndex = ZINDEX_OVER;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('shadow_map_container').style.zIndex = ZINDEX_UNDER;
}

function showHide()
{
    if(Options.mapVisible == true)
    {
        document.getElementById('shadow_map_container').style.zIndex = ZINDEX_UNDER;
        Options.mapVisible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('shadow_map_container').style.zIndex = ZINDEX_OVER;
        Options.mapVisible = true;
    }
}

var btnStr = '<a class="navTab" target="_top" onclick="showHide();return false;" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Shadow Mapper</span></a>';
var myNavContainer = document.getElementById('main_engagement_tabs');
var inner = myNavContainer.innerHTML;
var newStr = btnStr + inner;
myNavContainer.innerHTML = newStr;
```

Comment: Have you set your div to be positioned relatively or absolutely? If not the z-index will have no affect on the div.

Comment: @OriginalSyn updated my code above to include the creation of the div itself. yes, the position is set to absolute, and will pop over the game screen, if i can get it to work.

Comment: I should also add that when I change the boolean option variable involved, I can make the div appear just how I want it. For some reason my button isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a z-index problem, it's a coding style and event-listener problem.

You cannot activate a button that way in a Greasemonkey script.  `showHide()` resides in the GM sandbox, the page's JS cannot reach it from an `onclick`.
(One more, of many, reasons why inline JS should be avoided.)

In this example, you would activate the link like so:

```
function showHide()
{
    if(Options.mapVisible == true)
    {
        document.getElementById('shadow_map_container').style.zIndex = ZINDEX_UNDER;
        Options.mapVisible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('shadow_map_container').style.zIndex = ZINDEX_OVER;
        Options.mapVisible = true;
    }
    return false;
}

var btnStr = '<a class="navTab" target="_top"><span>Shadow Mapper</span></a>';
var myNavContainer = document.getElementById('main_engagement_tabs');
var inner = myNavContainer.innerHTML;
var newStr = btnStr + inner;
myNavContainer.innerHTML = newStr;

var btn = document.querySelector (".main_engagement_tabs > a.navTab");
btn.addEventListener ("click", showHide, true);
```

Comment: Hahaha! I found this solution almost exactly when reviewing proper syntax within GM. The only difference is I just used getElementById to get the needed div. Thanks!